# Windows 7 add user path variable for ffmpeg

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg

I am trying to add a user path varible for ffmpeg. It is located in D:\AppRun\FFmpeg\bin on my disk. In the Environment Variables dialog I clicked new and I entered ffmpeg for the varible name and D:\AppRun\FFmpeg\bin for the varible value. Clicked OK. Opened cmd prompt. Typed ffmpeg, and it says its not recognized as an internal or external command. What am I doing wrong??
I logged off and on but that did not help

Answer (score 0):

I put it in system path and it works. Still don't know why user path does not.